# Issue: Long Wait for Custom Outlook Add-In to Show Up for New Group Members in Microsoft 365

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, microsoft365

We have deployed a custom Outlook Add-in within our Microsoft 365 environment, targeting a specific Security Group. Our objective is to ensure that only members of this group have access to the add-in. However, we've encountered a consistent delay: when new members are added to the security group, it takes up to 24 hours for the add-in to become visible and accessible to them in Outlook.

This delay poses a challenge, especially when timely access to the add-in is critical for our workflow. We're looking for advice or solutions that could help expedite the propagation process, making the add-in available to new group members more swiftly.

Has anyone experienced a similar situation and found a workaround or a method to force or accelerate this propagation? Any insights into how Microsoft manages these updates and ways to potentially minimize this delay would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like the standard GAL update window..

Answer (score 0):

Outlook add-ins can take up to 24 hours to appear on app ribbons. See [Deploy add-ins in the Microsoft 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide) for more information.